# Change Value of $stateParams from controller angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my route provided:

```
.state('test.route', {
    url: '/test/:routeId',
    controller: 'RouterController',
    controllerAs: 'RCtrl',
    templateUrl:'app/components/test.view.html',
})
```

After redirecting to `RCtrl` I want value of `routeId` from `$stateParams` to be modified without calling `$state.go("test.route",{"routeId": 1231})`.

Comment: Get value $stateParams.routeId

Answer (score 0):

There's event emitted by uiRouter called `$stateChangeStart` when the transition begins. You can modify the `routeId` there

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){ ... })
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are in the state "test.route" and you want to modify the value of "routeId" in the controller, the only thing you have to do is to inject the dependency of "$stateParams" into "RouteController" and then modify it. See this example:

```
RouteController.$inject = ['$stateParams'];

function RouteController($stateParams) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.routeId = $stateParams.routeId;
  vm.routeId = '123123123123';
}
```

Comment: i want to modify `$stateParams.routeId` only, according to your solution after reloading page `$stateParams.routeId` will have original value.i Want to assign modified value only

Comment: After reloading this route will have original value but i want to assign `stateParams` modfied value

Comment: Sorry, i miss understood you.

So then you will have to use the uiRouter event "$stateChangeStart" and modify the param you want to. See this document:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki